# AddTapGesture not working for certain imageViews but not others

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using the interface editor to add tap gestures. I have a grid of 9 imageViews which are currently occupied by placeholders but upon touching, an imagePicker will trigger and the placeholders will replaced by actual images. I have a very infuriating bug that I've been mulling over for a few hours and can't figure out. My bottom 6 imageviews- the tap gestures seem to work. But for some reason, the top 3 imageviews don't respond to the taps. The weird thing is that if I tap outside of the circular placeholder and in the larger imageview that the placeholder is contained, it works. Any thoughts? I've made sure every grid is userinteractionenabled as well, and even tried deleting the buggy imageviews and creating new ones.

Comment: Show your view hierarchy

Comment: Select each TapGestureRecognizer and unselect "Cancels Touches in View".

Answer (score -1):

You can check the issue with layers in runtime. You can find out which layers are in above of UIImageView.

When you run the app and then select The Debug View Hierarchy tab at bottom of Xcode screen above of consol tab.